# group a column by names and get the corresponding values in pandas

Tags: sql, python-3.x

```
name games
a    football
a    volleyball
b    cricket
c    tennis
c    football


 a    football, volleyball
 b    cricket
 c    tennis, football
```

i want to groupby names and get the corresponding values.
i want something like this..
So when i call c, i should get corresponding two values like tennis, football

Comment: dbms name please

Answer (score 0):

use GROUP_CONCAT if your dbms is mysql

```
select name,GROUP_CONCAT(games) 
from table group by name
```